# Calling a method in a running thread, from outside the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a method in a thread that I want to call, whenever a certain event occurs in thread running parallel to it. Can I store the objects of the class on which the thread is running (lets say in a hashmap) and then directly refer to the object to invoke the method?

For example:

```
Class SomeThread implements Runnable{
SomeThread(){
}

    void run(){
          //do something
    }

    void someMethod(){
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Lets say multiple thread are created on this class:

```
while(someCondition){
   SomeThread st = new SomeThread();
   Thread t = new Thread(st);
   t.start();
   hashMap.put(unique_id, st)
}
```

Now, let's suppose the `hashMap` is visible to all of the thread created. Can I just access the `hashMap` using the `unique_id` to get the object of the thread I need and then call `st.someMethod()`?

EDIT: I'm asking this question from a P2P network programming perspective. Say a peer is listening for messages from other peers and once it gets a particular message, I need it to send another standard message to all other peers connected to it. In this case, can I just synchronize the method that sends this standard message?

Comment: Theoretically you can get the value from the map and call something on it, but that will still execute the method on the calling thread. Java objects does not belong to threads. You should at most *notify* the other thread of news and let the other thread wait / poll for notifies.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback :-)

Comment: @GhostCat Although I didn't end up using a shared data structure, I figured it answers the original question about whether I can use a certain approach. So, it's only fair that your answer be accepted. I do have other issues with my project but I guess that's for another fresh question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like this: threads don't own methods. A thread is nothing but a "sequence of activity".

Calling a method on a thread object will run that method within the same thread that is running the client code which invokes that method.

You should do that differently: one typically approach is that the other thread keeps polling the content of some shared data structure. Normally you would use some sort of queue for that.

Thread A puts some kind of command into a queue and thread B reacts to that at some point.

But please note: such designs are somehow "last decade". Nowadays you rather avoid using bare threads and low level interactions between them. Instead you look into advanced abstractions - such as ExecutorService, Futures,...

Comment: I did use a `BlockingQueue` before asking this question but that solution seemed kind of inelegant. I was just looking if there's an alternate way of going about it.

Answer (score 1):

Code running in any thread can invoke any accessible method on any object to which it has a reference.  Of course, the method runs on the thread that invokes it.

But multiple threads accessing the same shared objects must be properly synchronized, else the behavior of the resulting program is not well-defined, and may in practice exhibit all manner of surprising and counter-intuitive characteristics.  Synchronization is far too broad a topic to fully address here, but in your example, I would suggest at least

1. use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `java.util.HashMap`.
2. ensure that all access to shared state by `SomeThread.someMethod()` is properly synchronized, possibly by marking that whole method `synchronized`.

Comment: @tinkuge, nothing that you added in your edit gives me any reason to change anything in this answer, nor is it specific enough to warrant adding anything to this answer.  In particular, I cannot give a yes or no answer to your added question based on the information you have presented.  If you want a specific answer, present a [mcve] that is representative of your situation.